# copy-files error points to project name

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, osx-yosemite, google-compute-engine

When I try to copy a file from OSX to an instance following the documentaton I get this error 'Invalid value' pointing toward my project name SurplusServices.

```
bento@Bentos-MacBook-Air:~/Downloads$ gcloud compute copy-files /Users/bento/Downloads/bitnami-magento-1.9.1.0-0-linux-installer.run bento@as-magento:/var/www --zone us-central1-f

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.copy-files) Could not fetch instance:
 - Invalid value 'SurplusServices'. Values must match the following regular expression: '(?:(?:[-a-z0-9]{1,63}\.)*(?:[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?):)?(?:[0-9]{1,19}|(?:[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?))'

bento@Bentos-MacBook-Air:~/Downloads$
```

I've tried several permutations of the command, including and excluding `~/` and usernames, changed the paths, no joy.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Wow.  That took forever.  The command that worked is:                      gcloud compute copy-files ~/Desktop/bitnami_magento_installer.run bento@as-magento:~/bitnami/bitnami_magento_installer.run --project pristine-ally-667 --zone us-central1-f

Comment: I believe I went wrong trying to specify the path too literally by adding "/Users/bento/" and possibly I was missing the project id as well as per the official documentation.

Comment: Great to hear that you’ve solved your issue! Can you please move your solution into an answer and [accept it](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) so that this question is marked as closed? Thanks!